# NIntegrate stops working for particular values

Tags: numerical-integration

I was working on a problem for a project when suddenly I started getting very weird graphs where values randomly shot up for particular inputs. The actual problem is somewhat complicated, but I have managed to produce a simpler example where the same problem happens.

Suppose I want to integrate the function

$$ f(x,g) = \frac{x cos(gx)}{1+x^2} $$

with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $\infty$, and I want to analyze the resultant integral as a function of $g$. For this, I write a code in Mathematica:

```
f[g_] := NIntegrate[(x Cos[g x])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}];
LogLogPlot[f[g], {g, 0, 10}]
```

This is the plot I obtained:

[image]

There are these sudden jumps in value that happen at $g=0.199$ and $g=0.418$. When I plotted the function $f(g)$ between the values $0.42$ and $0.44$, this is what I got:

```
Plot[f[g], {g, 0.42, 0.44}]
```

[image]

Indeed, when I try to use NIntegrate for $g = 0.424$, it says that the integrand is highly oscillatory and the integral doesn't converge. However, if I use Integrate instead of NIntegrate to evaluate the same value,

```
Integrate[(x Cos[0.424 x])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

it gives a finite answer ($0.444085$).

I have no idea why this is happening. What is so special about $g=0.424$ that NIntegrate stops working only at this (and a handful of other) particular values?

Comment: Add option to NIntegrate: `Method -> "LevinRule", MaxRecursion -> 10`.

Comment: @Dris  `LogLogPlot[..]` doesn't show the negative values of `f[g] g>1`!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Well yeah, true. In my original problem, I was making log-log plots after taking the absolute value of f. I forgot to do the same here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Integrate[(x Cos[g x])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> g \[Element] Reals]
LogLogPlot[%, {g, 0, 10}]

(* 1/2 Sqrt[π] MeijerG[{{0}, {}}, {{0, 0}, {1/2}}, g^2/4] *)
```

Or use some big number (how big depends on your goal of accuracy) instead of infinity:

```
f[g_] := NIntegrate[(x Cos[g x])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, 10000}];
LogLogPlot[f[g], {g, 0, 10}]
```

Or you can use `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`:

```
f[g_] := NIntegrate[(x Cos[g x])/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
   Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"];
LogLogPlot[f[g], {g, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, symbolic integration works, as I mentioned in the post, but I need to use numerical integration for my particular question of interest because it is quite complicated and symbolic integration will take a very long time.

Comment: @Dris: I updated my answer.

Comment: Oh wow, that works! Any idea why NIntegrate breaks down for an infinite upper limit in the first place?

Comment: It is complicated integral and as it says it is highly oscillatory so it is not so easy to compute. You can also try using argument `WorkingPrecision`. With `WorkingPrecision -> 20` it gives nice output even with infinity upper limit. Even though there is some error mesaage.

Comment: Aah, that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @Dris: Another way is to use `Method -> "ExtrapolatingOscillatory"`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan `Method->"LevinRule" ` works too

Comment: If this is the right answer, why the downvote?